# Concurrent Calls from multiple clients to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, concurrency

I have a wcf service and I want to call it from multiple instances console applications (clients) and return the data from database row by row.
I want the service to not to duplicate the data, the data which has been received by one instance should not be received by another instance of the same client.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can have a column in your table called "IsRetrieved" and set it to true when your wcf method returns the data from the row (preferred approach). Or you can have a static member in your WCF that increments the row count when it returns a row. This will work only as long as the WCF service instance is in memory. IIS reset will mess you up. (not preferred approach, rather bad approach).